# List of Inno Setup pages in order with parameters and screenshot

Tags: inno-setup

What are all the Inno Setup pages that are available by default (no custom screens), how do they look like, what is their order, what is their default setting and how do I change the that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Inno Setup online help gives an overview of the [available Wizard pages](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=wizardpages). It lists most information you asked for. However it misses the default state, the section and the screenshot.

You can use this minimum Inno Setup script to see all dialogs yourself:

```
[Setup]
AppName=Stack Overflow
AppVersion=0.0.0.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\Stack Overflow
DefaultGroupName=Stack Overflow
VersionInfoVersion=0.0.0.0
OutputDir=compiled
WizardImageFile=LargeWizardImage.bmp
WizardSmallImageFile=SmallWizardLogo.bmp

DisableWelcomePage=no
LicenseFile=so.txt
Password=stack
InfoBeforeFile=info.txt
UserInfoPage=yes

[Components]
Name: "StackOverflow"; Description: "Demo component"; Types: full
Name: "TasksDemo"; Description: "Tasks component"; Types: custom

[Files]
Source: "SmallWizardLogo.bmp"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName: "Icon"
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\DemoIcon"; Filename: "Icon"

[Tasks]
Name: desktopicon; Description: "Create a &desktop icon"; GroupDescription: "Additional icons:"; Components: TasksDemo
```

Here they are, the ones which are hidden by default are struck through in the top right corner.

### Welcome Page

Parameter: `[Setup] DisableWelcomePage`
Default: `yes` (which means "not shown")

[image: Welcome Page]

### License Agreement

Parameter: `[Setup] LicenseFile`
Default: no license file (which means "not shown")

[image: License Agreement]

### Password

Parameter: `[Setup] Password`
Default: no password (which means "not shown")

[image: Password]

### Information

Parameter: `[Setup] InfoBeforeFile`
Default: no info file (which means "not shown")

[image: Information]

### User Information

Parameter: `[Setup] UserInfoPage`
Default: no (which means "not shown")

[image: user Information]

### Destination Location

Parameter: `[Setup] DisableDirPage`
Default: auto (which means "shown if not installed yet")

[image: Destination Location]

### Component Selection

Parameter: `[Components]` is not empty
Default: empty (which means "not shown")

[image: Component Selection]

### Start Menu Folder

Parameter: `[Icons]` is not empty and `[Setup] DisableProgramGroupPage`
Default: no icons (which means "not shown")

[image: Start menu folder]

### Select Tasks

Parameter: `[Tasks]` is not empty
Default: no tasks (which means "not shown")

[image: Select Tasks]

### Ready To Install

Parameter: `[Setup] DisableReadyPage`
Default: no (which means "shown")

[image: Ready To Install]

### Preparing To Install

Parameter: none, shown if files to be written are in use
Default: not in use (which means "not shown")

[image: Preparing To Install]