# Sound File Path - C# .Net

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a sound file that I want to play when the form loads. My sound file is in the `Resources` folder of my project:

```
C:\Users\myname\source\repos\Game\Resources
```

For now I want to run this form on my laptop but if I send someone else this project they obviously won't have the `Users\myname\source\repos\` part.

I'm having trouble figuring out what the file path would look like. I want the program to be able to locate the sound file if they run it on there laptop. I'm not sure if this makes a difference in the path. This is the code that I have so far in my form load:

```
 System.Media.SoundPlayer sp = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\myname\source\repos\Game\Resources");
 sp.Play();
```

My question is: do I need a different path so other people can use the sound file? And is this the correct way to play a sound file? (because when I run the form I don't hear the sound so I'm not sure if I'm missing something)

I tried looking this link but I'm still having trouble: [Add sound files to build, and find path? C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562719/add-sound-files-to-build-and-find-path-c-sharp)

Comment: In regards to your second problem, seemingly you have only given `SoundPlayer` a directory not a file.... To the first part, you would want to include the file as content and set it to copy in the properties in your project, or as a resource file.

Comment: Add file to project, set certain build actin (eg. copy to output directory), and then reference it with relative path.

Comment: Yes, you need a different path. Users other than you do not have access to your own user directory.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by copy to output directory? The way I got that address was by opening the project folder then going to Resources folder and then right clicking in the file manager bar at the top. Is that what you mean? @MichałTurczyn